# Calcular tiempo de respuesta para Progress Bar

Tags: c#, jquery, mysql, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Tengo una función en *AJAX* que devuelve un archivo. Lo que quiero hacer es implementar un **Progress Bar** con porcentaje para que el usuario sepa cómo va la descarga de su fichero. Uso *C# MVC4*, mi método en el controlador es un **FileResult**, y aquí muestro mi código en *jQuery*:

```
$('#DownBtn').on('click', function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Servicio/DescargaData",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'binary',
        beforeSend: function () {
            cargar();
        },
        success: function (result) {
            var url = URL.createObjectURL(result);
            var $a = $('<a />', {
                'href': url,
                'download': 'DataServicio.xlsx',
                'text': "click"
            }).hide().appendTo("body")[0].click();
            setTimeout(function () {
                URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
            }, 10000);
            noCargar();
        }
    });
});
```

Quiero agregar que para hacer eso, uso un archivo llamado `jquery.binaryTransport` que lo encontré googleando. No sé si es la menera correcta de hacerlo, como ven, pongo un `setTime` porque ese es el tiempo que calculé de la base de datos en mostrar los datos y el procesamiento. Pues, creo que está mal, necesito saber los porcentajes de procesamiento exactos desde el controlador.

Comment: he intentado editarla pero no puedo, como la elimino? quiero que esta se quede.

Comment: alguien me puede ayudar???

Comment: cristian, puedes ver alguna de [estas](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9541044/4092887) [respuestas](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2474601/4092887).